# Sorted order array mapped tries as foundation for sorted map implementation

Tags: data-structures, functional-programming

I am looking to implement an immutable key sorted map/set that is persistent (or at least have structural sharing) and has "good" complexity for merge/union operations, preferably one based on a tree with a high branching factor to keep the tree shallow. Phil Bagwell’s Ideal Hash Trees [paper](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/papers/idealhashtrees.pdf) introduces Sorted Order Array Mapped Tries, can they provide a suitable foundation to implement what I described? and are there any good reasons for the lack of any existing implementations.

Comment: Some of the reasons why Array Mapped Tries aren't used in applications where a sorted map is written to storage is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25952596/506816).